# How to set the limit for interated integral of $f(x,y)$ over diagonally partitioned region

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to compute $$I = \int_{\mathcal{R}} f(x,y) d\mathcal{R}$$

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} x^2, \quad  0 < x < y < \pi \\
      y^2  ,  \quad 0 < y < x < \pi \end{cases}$$

$\mathcal{R} = (0, \pi) \times (0, \pi)$

I haven't done this in years, how can I set the limits for the interated integral

$$I_x = \int_{\square}^{\square}\int_{\square}^{\square} f(x,y) dxdy$$

And 
$$I_y = \int_{\square}^{\square}\int_{\square}^{\square} f(x,y) dydx$$

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you draw your region, $y < x$ and $y > x$ then you will see this is the region below and above $y = x$, respectively.  In both cases, the outside limits will be $(0, \pi)$.  When you have "all" $x$ values, it will be the "below" region and it will go from $y = 0 \rightarrow y = x$ and when you have the "above" region the outside integral will go from $y \in (0, \pi)$ and it your $x$ will go from $(0, y)$...sketch a region--this will help (I may be wrong because I didn't do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture of the region with the two differential integrals labeled (if that makes sense):

[image]

Comment: So just $I_x = \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{y} x^2 dxdy$ and similarly for $I_y$? Okay I over thought it

Comment: @Lookbehindyou Yes, that is correct.  Whenever doing double integrals (or higher), you want to sketch a picture of the region (if possible).